# jquery click select option value with option text

Tags: jquery

i want to get select box option value and option text in click event using jquery my code is below

Html Code:

```
<select id="tskill" name="tskill" >
    <option value="1">One </option>
    <option value="2">Two </option>
    <option value="3">three </option>
    <option value="4">four </option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#tskill').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
});
```

If i click "four" in dropdown it will return id=4 but i want to get id with text "four". i used that syntax

```
 $(this).text();
 $(this).html();
```

But it will return whole select box text.
How can i get click able text value?

Comment: Why `onclick`? Are you not selecting an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `change` event instead of `click` like following.

```js
$('#tskill').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var text = $('option:selected', this).text(); //to get selected text
    alert(text)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="tskill" name="tskill" >
    <option value="1">One </option>
    <option value="2">Two </option>
    <option value="3">three </option>
    <option value="4">four </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are using `click` event to get the selected option value and text. If this is what you really want, then try below code.

```js
$('#tskill').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  
    alert(id + ', ' + text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="tskill" name="tskill" >
    <option value="1">One </option>
    <option value="2">Two </option>
    <option value="3">three </option>
    <option value="4">four </option>
</select>
```

---

---

Mean while

I would recommend using the `change` event handler to get the job done. Like this

```js
$('#tskill').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  
    alert(id + ', ' + text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="tskill" name="tskill" >
    <option value="1">One </option>
    <option value="2">Two </option>
    <option value="3">three </option>
    <option value="4">four </option>
</select>
```